# Example of metric space with given property

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Give an example of metric space that contains balls $B(x_1,r_1)\subsetneqq B(x_2,r_2)$, with $r_1>r_2$.

Was initially thinking about discrete metric, however, in discrete case one can never achieve a proper subset with given condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the metric on $\{0,1,2\}$ induced by the standard metric on $\mathbb R$, $B(0,1.2)\subsetneq B(1,1.1)$.

Comment: How did you come up with that? :<

Comment: @AlvinLepik: That question is much harder than the original question :-) I drew a picture of one circle containing another and wondered how their "centres" would have to lie for this to work out; that suggested that the "centre" of the inner circle would have to be "off-centre" and the outer circle would have to contain a point further away from it than from the outer circle's "centre".